# Split a python class over multiple files

Tags: python, class

There is a situation I constantly run into when refactoring python classes, and I am starting to wonder if I'm using some antipattern or if I'm missing some fundamental trick. The problem arises when I try to split large classes over multiple files, causing dependency pains.

Here is a small contrived example. Imagine an `Adult` class with very many methods, which have been grouped and extracted into seperate classes (`AdultFinances` and `AdultFamily`), which are added back in through composition. There is also a function `age_1_year` that returns an `Adult` instance, which is not added as a class method itself, but used in one (`age_somewhat`).

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass


class AdultFinances:
    def earn_money(self: Adult, amount: int) -> Adult:
        return Adult(self.name, self.age, self.money_in_the_bank + amount)

class AdultFamily:
    def have_kids(self: Adult, number: int) -> list[Kid]:
        return [Kid(f"child {i+1} of {self.name}") for i in range(number)]

class KidBiology:
    def grow_up(self: Kid) -> Adult:
        return Adult(self.name, 18, 0.0)


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Adult(AdultFinances, AdultFamily):  # composition
    name: str
    age: int
    money_in_the_bank: int

    # Some functionality is added as a method directly at the class.
    def age_somewhat(self, years:int) -> Adult:
        adult = self
        for _ in range(years):
            adult = age_1_year(adult)
        return adult


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Kid(KidBiology):  # composition
    name: str


# Seldom-used functions are not attached as methods.
def age_1_year(adult: Adult) -> Adult:
    return Adult(adult.name, adult.age + 1, adult.money_in_the_bank)


me = Adult("Rudi", 42, -400).earn_money(100).age_somewhat(1)
my_kids = me.have_kids(2)

# me = Adult(name='Rudi', age=43, money_in_the_bank=-300)
# my_kids = [Kid(name='child 1 of Rudi'), Kid(name='child 2 of Rudi')]
```

This works.

I now want to put `AdultFinances`, `AdultFamily` and `KidBiology` into their own file, as well as `age_1_year`, like so:

```py
# mixins.py

from main import Adult, Kid

class AdultFinances:
    # ...

class AdultFamily:
    # ...

class KidBiology:
    # ...


# tools.py

from main import Adult

def age_1_year(adult: Adult) -> Adult:
    # ...


# main.py

from dataclasses import dataclass

from mixins import AdultFamily, AdultFinances, KidBiology
from tools import age_1_year

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Adult(AdultFinances, AdultFamily):
    # ...

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Kid(KidBiology):
    # ...
```

This is where things go off the rails.

This setup causes an `ImportError` due to circular imports, and it's clear to see, why: `main.py` imports from `mixins.py` and `tools.py`, and these both import from `main.py`.

**What is the best-practice way of dealing with this problem?**

Remarks:

- This is a contrived example. I'm aware there are other solutions in this case, e.g. not use `age_1_year` in `age_somewhat`. But that's not the point. I'd like to know how to refactor exactly when there are these dependencies.

---

## Possible solutions

In this particular case, I *can* think of a few solutions, which I'll detail below. **However, they are cumbersome and/or do not scale. I'd like to find a solution that also works in more general cases and does not break my brain.**

### Solution 1: move (some) imports to bottom

The Big Idea: when we have a `import a` line in `b.py` and a `import b` line in `a.py`, we can move one of the imports to the final line of its file to avoid circular import errors.

**main vs mixins**

The `mixins` classes are used at the top-level of `main`. It must therefore be imported into `main` before the rest of the code in that file is run, so in `main`, we must keep the `from mixins import ...` statement at the top.

Therefore, in `mixins`, we must move the `from main import ...` statement down.

**main vs tools**

The `tools` function is not used at the top-level of `main`, but only when calling the method `age_somewhat`. Thus, in `main`, we *can* move the `from tools import ...` statement down.

Conseqently, in `tools`, we can leave the `from main import ...` statement at the top, leaving it unchanged.

The resulting files:

```py
# mixins.py

# (type-checking-part omitted)

class AdultFinances:
    # ...

class AdultFamily:
    # ...

class KidBiology:
    # ...

from main import Adult, Kid  # <- this is now at bottom


# tools.py

from main import Adult  # <- still unchanged at the top

def age_1_year(adult: Adult) -> Adult:
    # ...


# main.py

from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
from mixins import AdultFamily, AdultFinances, KidBiology # <- still unchanged at the top

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Adult(AdultFinances, AdultFamily):
    # ...

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Kid(KidBiology):
    # ...

from tools import age_1_year  # <- this now at the bottom
```

(Confusingly, a few lines needed to be added also to the top of the file - this is for type annotations, and not the subject of this question, so please ignore. For the exact lines, see further below. But again: not part of this question, so ignore, please.)

So: *where in `file_a` we must place the `import file_b` line depends on where in `file_b` we have the `import file_a` line.* I hope it is clear, that this is a nightmare to understand, maintain, and refactor. When there are more mixins or tools, each in their own file, it only becomes more complicated, esp. if they depend on each other.

### Solution 2: add references to other classes to make importing superfluous

The Big Idea: if we can get a reference to `Kid` and `Adult` from within the `mixins` and `tools` files via some other means, we can remove the imports in those files.

- To get a reference to the class of a given instance is easy: with `self.__class__` or `type(self)`.
- To get a reference to *another* class is not so easy. The only option we have (I think) is to sneakily add a reference to `Kid` from within `Adult`, and vice versa, like so:

```py
# main.py

# ...
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Adult(AdultFinances, AdultFamily):
    _kid_constructor = staticmethod(lambda: Kid)  # <- new. Must be function if 
                                    # Kid is defined further below.
    # ...

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Kid(KidBiology):
    _adult_constructor = staticmethod(lambda: Adult)  # <- new. Also made a function, 
                                    # for consistency.
    # ...
```

We can now use `adult._kid_constructor()(...)` to create a `Kid` object from within an `Adult` instance. And vice versa.

Here is the full solution, in which I've gone all-in on this idea and made *all* constructors available to *all* classes:

```py
# mixins.py

# (type-checking-part omitted)

class AdultFinances:
    def earn_money(self: Adult, amount: int) -> Adult:
        Adult = self.__class__      # <-- new. Alternatively:
                                    # self._constructors('Adult')
        return Adult(self.name, self.age, self.money_in_the_bank + amount)

class AdultFamily:
    def have_kids(self: Adult, number: int) -> list[Kid]:
        Kid = self._constructors('Kid')         # <-- new
        return [Kid(f"child {i+1} of {self.name}") for i in range(number)]

class KidBiology:
    def grow_up(self: Kid) -> Adult:
        Adult = self._constructors('Adult')     # <-- new
        return Adult(self.name, 18, 0.0)


# tools.py

# (type-checking-part omitted)

def age_1_year(adult: Adult) -> Adult:
    Adult = adult.__class__       # <-- new
    return Adult(adult.name, adult.age + 1, adult.money_in_the_bank)


# main.py

from dataclasses import dataclass

from mixins import AdultFamily, AdultFinances, KidBiology
from tools import age_1_year

def constructors(classname):
    return {"Kid": Kid, "Adult": Adult}[classname]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Adult(AdultFinances, AdultFamily):
    _constructors = staticmethod(constructors)   # <-- new
    # ...

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Kid(KidBiology):
    _constructors = staticmethod(constructors)   # <-- new
    # ...
```

I think this is slightly better than solution 1, but it's still very convoluted. Passing references back up to the parent classes by attaching them as a class method that are then accessed through the instances is really quite a mess, I think.

---

---

(Irrelevant and confusing to understanding the question, but needed if you want to play along at home: the line `# (type-checking-part omitted)` is short for

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from main import Adult, Kid
```

.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple tricks on the bag to be aware of when dealing with circular imports in Python:

1. You can import a module that hasn't been fully defined. If you import the module, using `import xxx` statement instead of `from xxx import MyClass`, then `MyClass` doesn't need to already be defined
2. You can enable postponed evaluations of annotations using `from __future__ import annotations`. This will allow annotations to contain invalid code/circular dependencies without affecting the runtime behaviour.

Your `mixins.py` and `tools.py` can look like so:

```
# mixins.py

from __future__ import annotations

import main


class AdultFinances:
    # Some functionality is added as class methods via composition.
    def earn_money(self: main.Adult, amount: int) -> main.Adult:
        return main.Adult(self.name, self.age, self.money_in_the_bank + amount)

    def spend_money(self: main.Adult, amount: int) -> main.Adult:
        return self.earn_money(-amount)


class AdultFamily:
    def have_kids(self: main.Adult, number: int) -> list[main.Kid]:
        return [main.Kid(f"child {i+1} of {self.name}") for i in range(number)]



# tools.py

from __future__ import annotations

import main


def age_1_year(adult: main.Adult) -> Adult:
    return main.Adult(adult.name, adult.age + 1, adult.money_in_the_bank)
```

You can also use `typing.Self` and `type(self)(...)`, which may be especially useful if there can be multiple classes that inherits from the mixin. This makes your code more generic, though IMO, for mixins that actually only have a single descendant, making the code more generic than it actually needs to be makes the type annotations less useful as it doesn't tell you what the final class actually are.

If you want a one sentence rule of thumb when to use `from x import y` and `import x` to avoid circular imports, then it would be this: **use from-import for forward imports, and module-import for reverse imports**.

Comment: See, I thought I had tried that and got tangled in circular dependencies... but in this case, the way you proposed, it does actually work. So.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I've done this kind of refactoring, I'll typically use a sort of diamond pattern where there's a "base" class that includes all the dependencies for the mixins.  Simplifying your example down a bit (making it a straight line rather than a diamond) it'd look like:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Self

# base layer
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class AdultBase:
    name: str
    age: int
    money_in_the_bank: int

# mixin layer
class AdultFinances(AdultBase):
    def earn_money(self, amount: int) -> Self:
        return type(self)(self.name, self.age, self.money_in_the_bank + amount)

    def spend_money(self, amount: int) -> Self:
        return self.earn_money(-amount)

# main layer
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Adult(AdultFinances):
    pass
```

That way there's no circular dependency, which means that if you split it into multiple files you don't have to do a lot of tricky stuff to try to get around circular imports.  The main thing is to "layer" your code so that the earlier layers don't depend on the later layers, e.g. the "mixin" layer should not reference `Adult` since that's in the "main" layer.

Arranging your code like this can also help you distinguish between the 'base' attributes that are fundamental to all the mixins, vs attributes that are only required by a specific mixin, vs attributes that are used by top-level methods that need to combine functionality from different mixins.  Having that kind of separation can help you reason about which parts of your code will be affected by changes to a particular attribute.

(Note: `typing.Self` is new in Python 3.11, but in older versions you can get the same effect with `TypeVar`s.)

Comment: Could it be that the main trick was to use `type(self)` in the mixin, which would have worked even without introducing `AdultBase`? (But adding the base layer is much clearer)

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer! I know about `type(self)`, or `self.__class__`, which is why I included the `.have_kids()` method my example. This is a mixin needing access to the bottom layer, as it returns an object (from a different class) from that layer.

Comment: The base layer is needed if you want the code to typecheck, since otherwise the typechecker won't know that an `AdultFinances` has a `self.name` etc.  (It will indeed work at runtime if you aren't doing static typechecking, provided that you don't use that mixin with a class that doesn't include those attributes.)

Comment: Could you expand your answer slightly, to include the other mixins? (I added a mixin for the kid, to reflect the use-case where there is cross-referencing from `Kid` to `Adult` and vice versa. So, `Kid` must also be in your main layer.)

Comment: TBH that's about the point where the dependencies in the interface itself are tangled enough that I'd be questioning whether the overall design makes sense.  Maybe `Adult`  and `Kid` should actually be `Protocol`s so that you can have the interface reference them without depending on the implementations?  But that's out of scope for what your question is asking.

Comment: Note that the new problem you've introduced is a circular dependency between `Kid` and `Adult`, which is distinct from the original problem of circular dependencies between your mixins and the class you're trying to build from them.

Comment: My goal was to create an example situation that can reasonably be expected in the wild. I agree there's a lot of coupling between `Kid` and `Adult`, but I think that's natural here, and I would like to know, how to handle exactly this kind of situation. 
- Other than, just putting all the code into one hugemonous file.